# Javascript - why return a closure with IIFE?

Tags: javascript, closures

I found a half decent explanation on closures a while ago on [this](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2013/02/25/getting-closure/) website. They present us with the following factory function to see a working closure:

```
var car;
function carFactory(kind) {
  var wheelCount, start;
  wheelCount = 4;
  start = function() {
    console.log('started with ' + wheelCount + ' wheels.');
  };

  // Closure created here.
  return (function() {
    return {
      make: kind,
      wheels: wheelCount,
      startEngine: start
    };
  }());
}

car = carFactory('Tesla');

// => Tesla
console.log(car.make);

// => started with 4 wheels.
car.startEngine();
```

Why does this person return the closure as a immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) that returns an object with the properties that he wants to share? I feel like the IIFE is unnecessary. If I would just return the object straight away, this would result in the same thing. Am I missing something?

```
  //Closure created here
  return{
    make: kind,
    wheels: wheelCount,
    startEngine: start
  };
```

Comment: It looks unnecessary to me, too.

Comment: It would make more sense if the IIFE took arguments, although even then they could just be variables in the enclosing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I don't think you are missing anything.

Just made to show the creation of a closure. If you just return the object it would not be considered one (not the best example though).

According to a [comment](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2013/02/25/getting-closure/#comment-813727826) of the author in that website:

> You need the self-executing function because that is the act that
>   creates the closure. JavaScript only has function-level scope so the
>   only way to bind the free variables into the enclosing scope is by
>   invoking a function.

Answer (score 0):

This could make sense if carFactory() whould be some object's method. Then the **this** of returned object (as self-invoked function) would be changed.

```js
var obj = {};

obj.funA =  function(){
  return {
    getThis:this
  };
};

obj.funB = function(){
  return (function(){
    return {
      getThis:this
    };
  })();
}

console.log(obj.funA());  //object
console.log(obj.funB());  //window
```